# What is the term for an ordered set/sequence containing natural numbers zero through x inclusive?

Tags: terminology, natural-numbers

Given a natural number `x`, what is the term (if any) for an ordered set or sequence that includes the range of numbers `0` through `x` inclusive, i.e.
given the natural number `4`, the set would be:

```
    { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

What would this set be called?  Is there any terminology that defines such a set?

Comment: The length-$(x+1)$ [initial segment](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InitialSegment.html) of $\mathbb{N}$? [von Neumann's representation of the finite ordinal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrdinalNumber.html) $x+1$?

Comment: I don't think there's a standard name for this.  $[0,n]$ is common when you're talking only about integers and there's no chance of confusing it with the real interval.